# Resize brackets for publication?

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I am unsure how to select appropriate size of brackets for different equations.

Example

```
\begin{equation}
(v, \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial t^{2}}) + c^{2}(\nabla v, \nabla u)
- c^{2} (v, \frac{\partial u}{\partial n})_{\partial \Omega} = (f,v).
\end{equation}
```

output

[image]

Example 2

```
\begin{equation}
\Big(v, \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial t^{2}}\Big) 
+ c^{2}(\nabla v, \nabla u)
- c^{2} \Big(v, \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\Big)_{\partial \Omega} = (f,v). 
\end{equation}
```

output

[image]

I think the last example is the best one because the brackets are as high as the inner thing.
**Is there any way to automatise the resizing of brackets for publication format?**

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `\left(` and `\right)`?

Comment: What do you mean by “publication format”? Either the typesetting is good or it is bad.

Comment: `\left(` and `\right)` are usually to big. Your second example is fine if you replace `\Big(` by `\Bigl(` and `\Big)` by `\Bigr)` I think.

Comment: @pluton `\left` and `\right` only make delimiters as big as you ask. If you do not like the default size then you should change `\delimtershortfall` and `\delimiterfactor`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your input seem to mean that you're using a kind of scalar product. In this case it's *recommended* to define your own command for it.

You can solve the “inner product” problem with `mathtools`; also a macro for partial derivatives *should* be defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\inprod}[2]{(}{)}{#1,#2}
\newcommand{\pder}[3][]{%
  \frac{\partial^{#1}#2}{\partial#3^{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\inprod[\Big]{v}{\pder[2]{u}{t}}
+ c^{2}\inprod{\nabla v}{\nabla u}
- c^{2} \inprod[\Big]{v}{\pder{u}{n}}_{\partial \Omega} = (f,v). 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\inprod*{v}{\pder[2]{u}{t}} 
+ c^{2}\inprod{\nabla v}{\nabla u}
- c^{2} \inprod*{v}{\pder{u}{n}}_{\partial \Omega} = (f,v). 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Now you're free to add the size of the delimiter as optional argument to `\inprod`; with `\inprod*` you choose automatic sizing, which should be done with care and only when necessary. Be consistent.

[image]